# The api requests are getting 404 error after one minute, which is working fine in my local, will be sharing the webpack-dev config file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, axios, webpack-dev-server

```
devServer: {
    assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
    assetsPublicPath: '/',
    proxyTable: {
        '/api/**': {
            target: 'http://xyz.dev2.lokal:8888/',
            changeOrigin: true,
            proxyTimeout: 10 * 60 * 1000,
            onProxyReq: (proxyReq, req, res) => req.setTimeout(10 * 60 * 1000)
        }
    },
```

How to set proxyTimeout in my webpack.prod config as the target api might differ at times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah the issue was resolved in local by making changes in webpack.
But our App is deployed in nginx where we need to change the configuration in the machine where the actual server is running..
1. change the configuration related to timeout under http section.
2. reload nginx
These things worked for me.

And webpack is designed to just help developers while developing the application.